# Threading issue with google guice and spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, deadlock, guice

I need to integrate an existing spring application with a custom elasticsearch river, ES rivers manage their dependencies using Google Guice and run in their own set of threads.

I've created a simple class which returns a static reference to spring context and configured a Guice module that returns objects from spring context. To ensure proper synchronization across guice threads and spring ones I've used a `CountDownLatch` released after the context is fully initialized. Here is some code

```
public class GuiceSpringIntegrator implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    private static final CountDownLatch contextLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Override public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        try {
            // check some stuff in context
        } finally {
            log.debug("Setting application context as static field of {}", getClass().getSimpleName());
            GuiceSpringIntegrator.context = event.getApplicationContext();
            log.info("Releasing latch for application context");
            contextLatch.countDown();
        }
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        if (null == context) {
            log.info("ApplicationContext not yet initialized, wait for it in thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Uninterruptibles.awaitUninterruptibly(contextLatch); <-- !!! SPRING INITIALIZATION CODE HANGS HERE
            log.debug("Returning application context since now context is initialized");
            Preconditions.checkState(context != null, "ApplicationContext should have been initialized properly");
        }
        return context;
    }
}
```

This is the guice module that uses the class above

```
/**
 * Guice module configuration
 */
public class ElasticSearchModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {}

    @Provides @Singleton TaskScheduler getSchedulerInstance() {
        return GuiceSpringIntegrator.getApplicationContext().getBean(TaskScheduler.class);
    }
    // and so on...
}
```

However when I start the application (especially on fast servers) occasionally the application hangs at the line marked in the above code. I double checked every code path which lead to the `#getApplicationContext()` method call and they are (should be) invoked by guice, so eventually the latch should be released and the code should proceed.

1. Is there a better way to handle this case?
2. Is there a way to check if I'm inside spring initialization code, something like [isEventDispatchThread for swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread--)? I'd like to use that code to trace if I'm calling `#getApplicationContext` from spring initialization code in some way?
3. Why `#onApplicationEvent` seems to be invoked before the context initialization is actually completed?
4. Any hint on how to debug this issue? I was reading about taking thread dumps on live server, is that right?

Comment: If you can reproduce the deadlock, analyzing the stack trace (e.g., `kill -3`) could indeed help. BTW, do you see your logging entries? Are you sure that onApplicationEvent is called?

Comment: @PhilippClaßen I'll try with `kill -3` I'm now looking for additional info about that. When the deadlock happens is because `onApplicationEvent` is not called, so my idea is that some configured spring bean indirectly calls `getApplicationContext` and the whole thing hangs.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question except for point #4, but I want to write code so I'm making it into an answer instead of a comment.

I would try changing this:

```
Uninterruptibles.awaitUninterruptibly(contextLatch); <-- !!! SPRING INITIALIZATION CODE HANGS HERE
```

to this:

```
boolean awaitResult = Uninterruptibles.awaitUninterruptibly(contextLatch, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
if(awaitResult) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to load Spring Context");
}
```

Then you can catch that exception somewhere and write it's stack trace to a log; this won't fix your problem but it likely will give you some more visibility into where the deadlock is?